# Foreign Key relationships in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, foreign-keys

I have a parent table and a child table.

Parent Table:
int AID, nvarchar parentname, nvarchar description

Child Table:
int CID, int AID, nvarchar childname, nvarchar address

Child table has got a foreign key(AID) from parent table. I need to display the list of Child table in view page. I'm new to asp.net mvc and the problem is, I'm not able to get the parentname to be displayed along with the childtable.

As we have foreign key, it should be possible to get the parentname using AID. Can anybody sort it out using some simple example. I'm struggling with this for the last 7hours.

Consider the Parent table to be an account and child to be a list of contacts associated with the account.

Parent Table => PID,PName, PAddress
Child  Table => CID,PID,CName,CAddress

Output Table => PName,CName,CAddress

Controller:

```
public ActionResult list()
{
var listing = db.child.FindContact().ToList();
return view(listing);
}
```

View snippet(.aspx):

```
<%: foreach(var a in Model) %>
{
<%: a.PName %>
<%: a.CName %>
<%: a.CAddress %>
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How are you accessing your database? EntityFramework?

Comment: What's the exact that problem you are facing? Are you not able to pull child records or you are having difficulty in showing child records using "View" for a given parent entry?

Comment: Hello, I've added some code to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create an object(ViewModel) that has all the properties from parent and a collection of children.

This is exactly how you need to do it..

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx